# Cordinator layout Collapsable app bar with wrap content for height

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to create a layout with a collapsable app bar like so

```
---------------------
<- My activity             (pinned)
---------------------
Some text and image 
that may go                (collapse paralax)
multiline
---------------------
Some fixed text            (pinned)
----------------------




     Recylcer view




-----------------------
```

All the examples I've seen on the net involve the collapsing view being an image so its a known size. I want to collapse a custom layout which has a dynamic height. Setting to wrap content causes the collapsing not to work. Using a fixed height makes collapsing work but i cant know what value to use at design time.

Is there a way to get coordinator layout to collapse a view inside CollapsingToolbarLayout when it has a dynamic height.

Xml layout for reference:

(note ive just put in a text view as the collapsable view but it is a more complex layout with text and images)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" <---- this is where i need wrap content, but it dont collapse untill a value is hard coded
            android:textAppearance="@style/TtlTextAppearance.Large"
            android:text="A very very long long sting indeed with loads of content that wont fit "
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/journey_header"
        layout="@layout/int_journey_header"
        android:layout_below="@id/fares_list_actionbar_extension"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/search_results_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/return_widget"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/return_widget"               
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/list_progress"
        layout="@layout/progress_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```